# codeigniter: Call to a member function send_message() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I wrote my code and run it on localhost correctly.
when I upload my project I found this error 
Contrller:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Controllers;
 use App\Models\ContactUS;
 class Admin extends BaseController
 {
  //contact us form
  public function contact_us(){
    //grabing message data
    $message_data = [
        "name"=> $_POST["name"],
        "email"=> $_POST["email"],
        "message" => $_POST["message"]

    ];
    $message_model = model(ContactUS::class);
    
    ** $send_message_data = $message_model->send_message($message_data);

    if($send_message_data){
        $data['status'] = 'success';
        $data['title'] = "about";
        echo view('template/header', $data);
        echo view('pages/about', $data);
        echo view('template/footer', $data);
    }else{
        $data['status'] = 'failed';
        $data['title'] = "about";
        echo view('template/header', $data);
        echo view('pages/about', $data);
        echo view('template/footer', $data);
    }
 }
}
```

model

```
<?php
  namespace App\Models;
  use CodeIgniter\Model;

  class ContactUS extends Model{
     protected $table = "contactus";
     protected $allowedFields = ['name', 'email', 'message', 'seen'];

     function send_message($message_data){
       return $this->insert($message_data);
     }
    }
 ?>
```

I see error "Call to a member function send_message() on null " on stared line from my host. But it's OK on localhost!!!

what should I do?

Comment: `print_r($message_data );` to see if it has any data or is null

Comment: I did that before. It has data correctly. this code worked on xampp localhost. but not work on website host!!!

Comment: Based on the error message alone, I would guess that `$message_model` is `NULL`

Comment: next step is to tell us what `$this->insert($message_data)` is actually doing, seems it returns null, hence the error

Comment: It's insert data to database

Comment: It sounds $message_model is null, chack your db connection infom, try `$message_model = new \App\Models\ContactUS(); ` and then check if the object is created or not ``dd($message_model)``;